# How to inject the product factory dependancy in plugin?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am a new Magento 2 user and I'm trying to develop a plugin, but iv been stuck on this problem for the past 2 days. I am trying to programmatically add a new product to the Magento 2 database. For this, I figured out I need to inject de product factory dependency to my custom plugin but I have no clue how to do this. I see there is a di.xml file in most plugins so I'm guessing this stands for Dependency Injection and I need to add the relevant code here but have no idea as to how to do this.

I am trying to use the product factory in Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php, this is my directory structure:

[image: My Dir Structure]

What do I need to write in di.xml to be able to get this dependency in Index's constructor?

This is my Index.php code:

```
        <?php

        namespace Sunoptic\Koppeling\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

        use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

        class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
        {
            private $_productFactory;
            private $_productRepository;

            public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory)
            {
                parent::__construct($context);
                $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
            }

            public function execute()
            {
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $result */
                $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
                $string = "";

                $result->setContents($string);
                return $result;
            }
        }
```

This returns error 500 probably because of the dependency problem.

I expect this error but have no clue how to actually add this dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Run Below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

you need to Run this command every time new dependency is injected to any class through class or di.xml.

open debug mode so you can see error in any case.

```
php bin/magento setup:debug:mode developer
```